Реализовал JWT авторизацию с помощью symfony и vue3
Реализовал JWT авторизацию с помощью symfony и vue3.
Сохраняю token в localStorage.
Есть функция loadToken
которая каждый раз обновляет токен если она есть.
Она вызывается в router.js.
Правильно ли я делаю что я делаю вызов функция loadToken?
и каждый раз вытаскиваю токен и кладу в store.Может есть вариант полегче?
2.Есть апи которая с данными пользователя.
Стоит ли записывать также в localstorage пользователя как и с токеном?
если в данных пользователя лежит роль, которая нужна для того чтобы запретить пользователю доступ к определенному компонету?
export const auth = {
namespaced: true,
state() {
    return {
        token: null,
        refreshToken: null,
    };
},
mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
        state.token = token;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    },
    clearToken(state) {
        state.token = null;
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
    },
    setRefreshToken(state, refreshToken) {
        state.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refreshToken);
    },
    clearRefreshToken(state) {
        state.refreshToken = null;
        localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
    }
},
actions: {
    loadToken({state, commit}) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
        const isValid = isValidToken(token);
        if (token && isValid) {
            state.token = token;
            state.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        } else if (!isValid) {
            commit('clearToken')
            commit('clearRefreshToken')
        }
    },
}
}


в куки можно токен передавать

да,а как быть с сохранением токена в store.
стоит ли вызывать каж.раз loadToken?
